# Removing directly connected route from routing table in Linux

Tags: routing, lan, linux

I have an interface that is added as a directly connected route in my routing table. (FLAG is only U)
How can I remove this route from the routing table.
route del doesn't appear to affect directly connected routes.

env is Linux, Ubuntu Server 14.04, The interface is a normal LAN connection.

Comment: Use `ip route`. It will have to be purged every time the interface comes up as it's automatic. Removing the route will prevent sending of traffic (and potentially *receiving* as well)

Answer (score 3):

The connected route is generated automatically by the kernel from the prefix length (or netmask) associated with the interface.  In order to avoid the connected route, you need to set a prefix length of /32 (or /128 in IPv6):

```
# ip addr show dev eth0
...
    inet 10.0.0.42/24 scope global eth0
...
# ip addr del 10.0.0.42/24 dev eth0
# ip addr add 10.0.0.42/32 dev eth0
```

Answer (score 2):

Shut down the interface.

`sudo ip link set ethX down`

EDIT: If you still wish to receive packets on the interface, then you'll need to remove the IP address configuration of the interface from `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: This is obvious, But I still want to receive packets from that interface. I just don't want it to exist in the routing table.

Comment: Understood. See edits to the answer.